# Dell Inspiron 7737 with Windows 7 Wlan connection fail

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, laptop, dell-inspiron

I just got my new Dell Inspiron 7737 Laptop and installed Windows 7 on it. I found all the drivers coresponding to this model and all drivers are working well.

Now my problem is:

First time I connected to my wlan (I´m using two wlans in a big flat) there was no problem at all. I connected to the first and checked the "Allways connect to this network" checkbox. I did the same thing with the second wlan... No problem.

Now, after a week of working with the new laptop, I consider problems with the wlan adapter... mostly I do not shot-down the laptop, I just close the display cover for sending laptop in standby mode. After waking it up again (opening cover, press power, windows is resuming session) the laptop does´nt connect automatically to both of the wlans.
When I try to connect manualy I get the message: "Connection to WLAN is not possible" (not exactely this words, because I have a german version).

Then I click on "Resolving network problems", Win7 starts to check for connection problems and after a while (saying "Reseting network adapter") the laptop connects automatically to the primary wlan... Like there never was a problem...

I don´t think that the problem is on the wlan-router because of following reasons:

```
1) I use two different models for two wlans, the problem occurs on both routers

2) I use the wlan extensively with two smart phones and two other laptops - no problem
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem would be much apriciated.

Thank you in advance for your ideas.

Best regards,

Ingmar

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to your WLAN adapter being in power save mode. Check your device settings and if it is checked to turn off the adapter on the power / advanced tab, uncheck and save. That should resolve the issue